# Search content in specific pages on Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to figure if its possible to search for strings in specific pages on Facebook's Graph API (version 2.5) or all searches abilities has been blocked?
There is any other wat to do so?
[Here is the only search methods that i found](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found everything that is possible to search for. You can´t search for strings on Pages, you can only get the feed and and search for the string with your programming language of choice.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed

Comment: i didn't saw how can i get the whole feed of page/user in the API

Comment: i added a link to the docs. same for user (with the /me/feed endpoint), just use the docs (and google).

Comment: thanks a lot, thats probably the way to look for content with Graph API after facebook blocked the search